# Increase block gas limit hardhat

Tags: gas-limit, hardhat

I'm just running some tests with massive functions, and I keep running into

```
InvalidInputError: Transaction gas limit is 30429720 and exceeds block gas limit of 30000000
```

How do I increase the block gas limit in hardhat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `hardhat.config.js` increase the `blockGasLimit`

```js
module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            blockGasLimit: 100000000429720 // whatever you want here
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an option like `allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,`, you might find its usage below. In one place I found `Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit` might appear by different reasons and cannot estimate gas might throttle the main error -- can not prove it in my experience, when I had increased gas limit the issue was disappeared, but it is important to keep it in mind.

```
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
    }
  }
  
};

export default config;
```